# Android Volley BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 412

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have this Error in my logcat.
I use Volley to send a request.

```
E/Volley﹕ [2040] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 412 for http:/myserver/index.php
```

And nothing, no other error.
No line error, nothing.

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Create Custom request and override getParam() method

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;    
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;    
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;

public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
private Map<String, String> params;

public CustomRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params,
        Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
    this.listener = reponseListener;
    this.params = params;
}

public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
        Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.listener = reponseListener;
    this.params = params;
}

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
    return params;
};

@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listener.onResponse(response);
}
}
```

And put these lines in activity

```
CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Method.POST, url,params, this.createRequestSuccessListener(),  this.createRequestErrorListener());
requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

If it not works then before make request clear cache
    **requestQueue.getCache().clear();**

Answer (score 1):

Just in case my answer works for someone!
So, I was using POST request but not sending any params along with the request. When I replaced POST with GET, everything worked fine. Note that I do not need to send any params along with the url.

Answer (score 0):

FML, sorry for this question.

The problem was my name's page. It was not index.php but indexx.php on my server

A bad mistake...

Mayve this answer will ans other guys like me ^^

Answer (score 0):

When your Api not found the path of your url in Server,then you get 404,403 error or BasicNetwork.performRequest() unexpected response code 404,if you check in PostMan you get Html response,

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        newTworkError(error);

 if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Our server is busy please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "AuthFailure Error please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Parse Error please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 

else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "No connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Server time out please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }error.printStackTrace();}
```